What is the formula for PMF from adding independent zero-modified negative binomial random variables?
Let $X$,$Y$,and $Z$ be independent identical zero-modified negative binomial (ZMNB) random variables, then how would the probability mass function (PMF) be calculated?
$$P(X + Y + Z = k) = ?$$
For example, how would you calculate probabilities for $k=\{0,1,2,3\}$?
I am thinking I need to combine the probabilities generated by the ZMNB with the binomial or multinomial theorems to get right combined probabilities, but I'm not sure how to go about it.
Information on the ZMNB and zero-modified distributions in general can be found here and here.
